# How to get Selected color value in rgb format with using colorPickerUIAdv1 Control of Syncfusion in C# in Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, color-picker, syncfusion

I have Syncfusion Control i.e. colorPickerUIAdv1 control and i want to get the Selected value of that colorPicker dialog box. Any Help or your suggestion is appreciated.Thanks in adavance.[image: My colorPickerUIAdv1 Control]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved my problem using this line :

```
 selectedcolor = colorPickerUIAdv1.SelectedColor.ToArgb();
```

The selected color is getter setter property  of int type and i have successfully getting RGB value from colorPickerUIAdv1.
Thank you all for taking your helpful time to answering me or giding me...your solution work not getting question i.e. Selected colors RGB value from colorPickerUIAdv1.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected color using the following property

```
this.colorPickerUIAdv1.SelectedItem.Color;
```

And you can get through the following events of the colorPicker control

```
    private void colorPickerUIAdv1_Picked(object sender, Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Tools.ColorPickerUIAdv.ColorPickedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.splitContainerAdv1.Panel1.BackColor = this.colorPickerUIAdv1.SelectedItem.Color;
    }
```

more detailed information you can check the samples which they provided on the [github](https://github.com/syncfusion/winforms-demos/tree/master/Tools.Windows/Samples/ColorUI%20Controls/ColorPickerUI)

Comment: I have use this  and i  will solved my problem    :                                      
 selectedcolor = colorPickerUIAdv1.SelectedColor.ToArgb();

Answer (score 0):

This reported requirement can be achieved by using Picked event in ColorPickerUIAdv.

Reference: https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/colorpickeruiadv/events#picked-event

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Kannan

Comment: i will solved my problem using this line but not posted the answer : selectedcolor = colorPickerUIAdv1.SelectedColor.ToArgb();